# Does WPF's TextBox support spell-check dictionaries for the Netherlands?

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization, internationalization, richtextbox

The RichTextBox supports a spellcheck option which is very nice. (SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true)

But I cannot seem to get it to another language. (I live in the Netherlands.. ;))

Does any of you have an experience with the SpellCheck option of TextBox?

I know it can be change by changing the keyboard settings, but I want to change it in the application.

What I have tried so far (and did not work):

- Changing the CurrentCulture on the current Thread.
- Changing the Language property in xaml in "nl-NL"
- Changing the Language property in code with the `XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("nl-NL");`

You should not get any spelling errors with the following line:

"Dit is een Nederlandse tekst."

The RFC 3066 language key of my language is "nl-NL"

Many thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 1):

Spelling support for WPF is limited to just 4 languages; English, Spanish, French, and German.

Using a custom dictionary will only add "special words" to the current dictionary. It will not allow a new language dictionary.